# Windows 10 on old netbook - should I install the 32 bit or 64 bit OS?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, lenovo-laptop, 32-bit, netbook

I have an old laptop that I would like to use mainly for some coding with ATOM and photo editing with GIMP and/or Photoshop CS2. 
Should I install the 32 or 64 bit version of Windows 10?

Laptop specs:

```
1.6GHz N270 Intel Atom Processor
2GB PC2-5300 DDR2 SDRAM 667MHz
Windows 7 PRO
10.1″ WSVGA Glossy LED-backlit display with integrated camera 1024×600
160GB 5400rpm Western Digital Scorpio Blue hard drive
Intel GMA 950 Integrated Graphics
```

Comment: It's not possible to use a 64-bit operating system on processors that don't support the 64-bit x86 instructions.  So it's not possible to install a 64-bit installation of Windows 10 on the hardware you have.  This question shows no research effort (Intel provides specifications on all of their processors) a simple google search would have verified your hardware capabilities

Comment: Voting to close because this is basically you polling is on what you should do but in reality you only have one option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like **32-bit is possible** to do from [Microsoft's site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications).

[image]

As Ramhound already pointed out, [your processor does not seem to support 64-bit.](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB)

[image]

Another thing to note is that while it may meet the "Minimum" requirements, is does not mean it will run well.

Comment: If you want to be specific about the support of the processor it would be worth showing an image of the Intel Ark page which shows that the processor is 32-bit only: http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB

Comment: @Mokubai Done, gotta make a habit of doing that.  Thanks!